# Spring h2 database error when trying to save

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

Every time I try to save to springboot h2 database it crashes with the below error, I can't seem to do anything to fix it. I have attached the code also. I'm quite new to spring.

I follow some tutorials online but I am stuck at this point.

> 2019-08-14 23:17:33.559  INFO 6296 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
>   DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2019-08-14 23:17:33.559  INFO
>   6296 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2019-08-14 23:17:33.567  INFO
>   6296 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   Completed initialization in 8 ms 2019-08-14 23:17:33.607 ERROR 6296
>   --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   com.test.lottery.lottery.LotteryController.CreateTicket(LotteryController.java:36)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]

The code

```
@Entity

public class TicketRequest {
    int id;
    Boolean checked;
    Map<Integer, int[]> num_lines;


    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    @Column(name = "id")  
public int getId(){
    return id;
}

    @Column(name = "checked")  
public Boolean getChecked(){
    return checked;
}

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "ticket_num")  
public Map<Integer, int[]> getTicketNum(){
    return num_lines;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}

public void setTicketNum(Map<Integer, int[]> num_lines){
    this.num_lines = num_lines;
}
```

code for @RestController:

```
@RestController
public class LotteryController {

       private TicketRepository TicketRepository;

  @RequestMapping("/ticket")
  public TicketRequest CreateTicket(@RequestParam int line) {

      Map<Integer, int[]> lottery_lines = new HashMap<Integer,  int[]>();

      for(int i = 1; i<= line; i++) {
          int[] ints = new Random().ints(0, 3).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
          lottery_lines.put(i,  ints);

     // System.out.println("The Value are: " + Arrays.toString(lottery_lines.get(0)));
     } 

      TicketRequest response = new TicketRequest();
      response.setId(1);
      response.setChecked(false);
      response.setTicketNum(lottery_lines);


      TicketRepository.save(response);

    return response;

  }

}
```

```
public interface TicketRepository extends CrudRepository<TicketRequest, Integer>{

}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the issue? Have you tried going through the logs and narrowing down the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add @Autowired annotation for TicketRepository in your controller .

It seems that TicketRepository in controller is null , because you are not injecting TicketRepository as bean.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at that stack trace, the error is unrelated to H2, you are getting a null pointer on line 36 in your controller. Unforunately, I can not tell which line is number 36 from  your code.

Have a good look line 36 and try to identify what could be null.

My guess is that line 36 is `TicketRepository.save(response);`. TicketRepository is never initialised in your code. You are probably just missing an `@Autowire` on that field.

Answer (score 1):

The TicketRepository TicketRepository in the LotteryController requires an **@Autowired** notation.

```
@RestController
public class LotteryController {

    @Autowired           
    private TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/ticket")
    public TicketRequest CreateTicket(@RequestParam int line) {

      Map<Integer, int[]> lottery_lines = new HashMap<Integer,  int[]>();

      for(int i = 1; i<= line; i++) {
          int[] ints = new Random().ints(0, 3).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
          lottery_lines.put(i,  ints);

     // System.out.println("The Value are: " + Arrays.toString(lottery_lines.get(0)));
     } 

      TicketRequest response = new TicketRequest();
      response.setId(1);
      response.setChecked(false);
      response.setTicketNum(lottery_lines);


      ticketRepository.save(response);

    return response;

  }

}
```

The Spring Container is responsible for managing the beans and it injects the **TicketRepository** bean when you annotate with the @Autowired annotation.